# Create my own JWT server auth or use a library like auth0

Tags: php, database, angular, authentication, jwt

I am just learning about JWT and Authentication in general, its my first real look inside this world so Its all abit overwhelming.

I wanted to add login/general sessions for my new site (Angular 2 SPA), and after abit of research JWT seemed to be the best approach, so I got [php-jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) and setup a super basic authentication with my basic database shown here:

```
class userAuth {
    // create an empty id variable to hold the user id
    private $id;
    private $email;
    private $key = "16FD8C979FC40CCB97457F4AD79B32A73758771B4D1943C379FB3266EECE0C3E";

    // Checks if the user exists in the database
    private function validUser($email, $password) {
        $conn = new mysqli(DBSERVER, DBUSERNAME, DBPASSWORD, DBNAME);
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        $truepassword = hash('sha256', $password); // password hashing using SHA256
        $query = $conn->query("select * from  users where ( username='$email' OR email = '$email') and password='$truepassword'");
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if($count == 1) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
            $this->id = $row['id'];
            $this->email = $row['email'];
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    private function genJWT() {
        // Make an array for the JWT Payload
        $payload = array(
            "id" => $this->id,
            "email" => $this->email,
            "exp" => time() + (60 * 60)
        );

        // encode the payload using our secretkey and return the token
        return JWT::encode($payload, $this->key);
    }

    public function checkUser($email, $password) {
        // check if the user exists
        if ($this->validUser($email, $password)) {
            // generate JSON web token and store as variable
            $token = $this->genJWT();
            $resultJSON = array(
              'email' => $this->email,
              'token' => $token
            );
            return json_encode($resultJSON);
        } else {
            return 'We Couldn\'t Find You In Our Database. Maybe Wrong Email/Password Combination';
        }
    }

    private function validJWT($token) {
        $res = array(false, '');
        // using a try and catch to verify
        try {
            //$decoded = JWT::decode($token, $this->key, array('HS256'));
            $decoded = JWT::decode($token, $this->key, array('HS256'));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $res;
        }
        $res['0'] = true;
        $res['1'] = (array) $decoded;

        return $res;
    }


    public function validLogin($token) {
        // checks if an email is valid
        $tokenVal = $this->validJWT($token);

        // check if the first array value is true
        if ($tokenVal['0']) {
            // create user session and all that good stuff
            return "Everything went well, time to serve you what you need.";
        } else {
            return "There was an error validating your email. Send another link";
        }
    }
}
```

And this was good to get my head around the idea of JWT auth, I managed (after hours mind you) to collect the token and save it to local storage on a successful login. **but** I tried to use a jwt library to properly manage getting info with my token etc I couldnt get it to work, beccause I imagine my setup doesnt provide what the lib expects the token to be formatted or something along those lines

Would it be a good idea to try and just continue and learn as I go in this manner, because at the moment I havnt found many resources or tutorials on building my own JWT backend, or how I would talk to said backend correctly.

I have now setup a basic auth0 account and im looking into/testing that usage, would I be better off learning on my own, or using a lib (happy to be referred to, to other JWT API's that work with angular 2, or would be appropriate for it).

I also dont like the idea of my server backend being someone else's if that makes sense.